# Mongo DB replica set how to config replication for specific collection database

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

How to config Mongo DB replica set to replicate only for specific collection database or even database?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It would contradict the main idea of a replication.

Comment: so can u please describe 
change-streams section 
"Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a collection or collections"
at official documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/#change-streams